# PHP random string

Tags: php

I would like to print random values in my page.
I wrote this code but it is not working:

```
    $claim[1] = "Red";
    $claim[2] = "Blue";
    $claim[3] = "Yellow";
    $claim[4] = "Purple";
    $claim[5] = "Magenta";
    $color = $claim[mt_rand(1,2,3,4,5)];
```

Any idea?

Comment: *How* does it not work? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? What have you done to debug this?

Comment: John I expect the page where I write <?php echo $color; ?> to print one of the colors above. But it does not print anything

Comment: Where do you come up with `mt_rand(1,2,3,4,5)`? The manual clearly explains with what kind of parameters this function can be called, does it not? You mustn’t wonder that your stuff doesn’t work, when you go and invent your own bogus nonsense syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need a random number between 1 to 5:

```
$claim[1] = "Red";
$claim[2] = "Blue";
$claim[3] = "Yellow";
$claim[4] = "Purple";
$claim[5] = "Magenta";
$color = $claim[rand(1,5)];
```

optional: but you can use array_rand too (Return an array of random keys):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand

```
$claim[1] = "Red";
$claim[2] = "Blue";
$claim[3] = "Yellow";
$claim[4] = "Purple";
$claim[5] = "Magenta";
$color = $claim[array_rand($claim)];
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!